# Will my lasagna be ruined because I forgot to put the white sauce on the lasagna sheets

Tags: sauce, lasagna

I was making lasagna and put in the meat and the lasagna sheets but then I realized (after I had finish the layers and the cheese top), I forgot to put the white sauce on top of each layer of lasagna sheets, will this ruin the lasagna?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) when you get a chance. The answer to this question will depend on what you consider 'ruined'; in general it is always helpful if you could share the recipe you used.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Anecdotal, I rarely use white sauce in lasagna and it always rocks.

Comment: Might be worth adding that you need enough moisture in your meat/bolognese for the lasagna sheets to cook properly and not become dried up sheets of rock.